# ASP.NET Core 7 : no value was provided for the required property while adding migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I'm trying to add a migration using

```
dotnet ef migrations add _initial
```

I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'TextField' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'MetaKeywords'

I'm creating a backend for a simple web page.

Here is part of class I created to inherit entities from:

```cs
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    protected EntityBase() => DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;

    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    //...

    [Display(Name = "metatag Keywords")]
    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
}

public class TextField : EntityBase
```

If I initialize `MetaKeywords`, I'll get same error about similarly defined property `MetaDescription`.

Why are these properties required? I didn't add the `Required` attribute to any of them.

Answer (score 0):

So I made properties mentioned in exception nullable and it solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).